# In PAMGuard how do you paste a known Spectrum of Species over Click Detection Spectrum?

Tags: pamguard, troubleshooting

When looking at PAMGuard Viewer (Version 2.02.02) and classifying new species events after running a click detector I know there is a way to paste an example spectrum on top of the 'Click Spectrum' window to use as a reference but I do not remember all of the steps.

I know that you should:

1. Show Events in the Click Detection dropdown
2. Go to the example event you want to use the spectrum and click on a click
3. Right Click in the 'Click Spectrum' window and go to 'Manage Templates'
4. Select the event that you want in the window (which would be the average)
5. Click on 'Add Spectrum' and Export the template to where you want to save it

After those steps, how do you load the Spectrum in the 'Click Spectrum' Window so you can use the template created on any given event as a comparison?

Comment: Could you please specify which version of PAMGuard you are using?

Comment: Hi Chloe, So sorry I did not include that... I am using PAMGuard Version 2.02.02.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you outline, you need to build a template first. This can be done externally or within PAMGuard. Here, I have selected the high amplitude clicks from a harbor porpoise event.

[image: screen shot of PAMGuard Click Detector with the high amplitude clicks collected in an event.]

By right-clicking within the Click Spectrum window, you click Manage Templates.  That will bring up the following menu, where you can add a template based on any event you have created, or import one.

[image: screen shot of PAMGuard Manage Template menu.]

Here's where you're getting tripped up: You need to EXPORT the click template and save it. You can not just load it directly to your Click Spectrum.  So export the template and save it in your working directory.

Then, either in the Manage Templates menu or directly from right-clicking on the Click Spectrum, you can add the template.

[image: Click Detector window in PAMGuard with click template added.]

Comment: I tried this with your instruction and it worked!! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hey Alexandra! If you accept my answer it helps both of our point totals. :)

Comment: Oh so sorry, I am still getting used to this platform, thank you!!

Comment: No worries!! 

Answer (score 6):

To load a click spectrum that you have saved previously, right click on the Click Spectrum plot> Add template> Browse> Navigate to where you saved your template then click Ok. Now click on another click in the Bearing-Time plot and you should see your saved template overlay the current click.